# Word for someone who thinks everything is about them

Tags: single-word-requests

I have an ex, and the other day she asked why I was hiding my last seen on Whatsapp, and I assume she thinks it's because I'm trying to avoid her; but in reality I only do it to avoid other certain people if I don't feel like answering. Not about her at all. She's done this before with others things. I'm over her, and she's clearly not and still thinks she's the center of my universe.

What word would describe her or her behavior?

Comment: Something similar to "paranoid", "vain", "conceited" and mixed with having a low self esteem.

Comment: I think a word like [egocentric](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/egocentric) would be a decent answer to this question, without it being necessarily opinion-based... hence I voted to re-open.

Comment: If it is not about her then it's all about you. Why does it have to be all about _you_?

Answer (score 0):

Your ex would appear to be 'conceited'.

'Excessive pride in oneself.'

Oxford English Dictionary.
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/conceit

'Her conceit about her beauty annoyed many people.'

Conceit, used in a sentence.
http://www.use-in-a-sentence.com/english-words/c2/conceit.htm

Answer (score 0):

Your ex sounds like a [narcissist](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/narcissist)

Not a moral judgment, just the closest word I know to your description.